# Creating a database remotely using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm trying to create a database by remote connecting to a SQL Server Express using Visual Studio 2008.  I log onto SQL Server using SQL Authentication.  I can do that remotely using SQL Server Management Studio Express no problem by using the following command:

> CREATE DATABASE dbname ON
>   (NAME='dbname_dat',
>   FILENAME='C:\folder\dbname.mdf') LOG
>   ON (NAME='dbname_log',
>   FILENAME='C:\folder\dbname.ldf')

However, when I use the same line in my code, I get the following error:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in
>   database 'master'.

Error number is 262 and class number is 14.  My connection string is:

> server=servername;database=master;trusted_connection=yes;Pooling=false;

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Well, the error message tells you what is wrong, doesn't it? The user you use to log into via C# doesn't have sufficient permission to execute CREATE statements.

You seem to use a different user to log in via SQL Server Management Studio than to log in via C#. Do you log into the SQL server via Windows Authentication and via SQL Server authentication in C#? Or maybe in Management Studio you have selected a different database in which to execute the sql statement? Check the combobox for the database the script uses.

Answer (score 2):

This is too obvious, but check your permissions on the server. Are you a sysadmin or a dbcreator?

Also, check your user credentials. Your connection string says `trusted_connection=yes` but then you say that you are logging in using SQL Server authentication. Which one are you or should you be using?

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your connection string to something along the lines of this (Note the User and Pwd settings):

`tmpConn.ConnectionString = "SERVER = " + DBParam.ServerName + 
                         "; DATABASE = master; User ID = sa; Pwd = sa";`

The sa account would have the rights to do this command.

Comment: Little things.  Yes this was the problem.  Thanks.  I had been working so long with Windows Authentication, my code for SQL Server Authentication wasn't all that it could be.  But that's why we test.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that your credentials are not being passed through to the database.  If this is a website, this could happen for a number of reasons:

- You don't have impersonation turned on
- You have basic authentication turned on in IIS..

See this article on MSDN about [How to Access SQL Server Using Windows Integrated Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx) 
 for detailed instructions about setting up integrated security, or switch to a fixed SQL Server account.